# How to improve run time of a loop for a big database?

Tags: vba

For every ID on my database i have to sum all the concepts linked to them. For example ID 2354 has 3 concepts, each one on a different row, i have to sum the amount of the 3 concepts, paste that sum on the cell where the amount of the first of this concepts originally was, and then eliminate the entire row of the second and third concepts.

My macro already do this, but the running time is very high, and my database is huge, around 100,000 rows, i need a way to improve the running time. Here is the code i have:

```
Sub Macro1()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.EnableEvents = False
ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False

Dim t As Long
Dim a As Integer
Dim i As Integer

lastt = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row  vacía
For i = 1 To 30
    If Cells(1, i).Text = "Report Legacy Key" Then
        For t = 2 To lastt 
            For a = 1 To 40
                primera = Cells(t, i).Value
                ultima = Cells(t + a, i).Value
                repetidas = Range(Cells(t, i + 1), Cells(t + a, i + 1))
                If primera = ultima Then
                    c = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(repetidas)
                    Cells(t, i + 1).Activate
                    ActiveCell.Value = c
                    Range(Cells(t + 1, "A"), Cells(t + a, "AB")).Select
                    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
                End If


            Next a

            If IsEmpty(Cells(t + 1, "A").Value) = True Then
                Exit For
            End If
        Next t
    End If
Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Range("M1").Select

Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

This code allows to do the process for 1000 rows in about 15 seconds, which is very slow, considering it has to be done for around 100,000 rows.

Comment: Just one word, arrays. With large data you need to use arrays alongside dictionaries if needed. Fastest way to work them.

Answer (score -1):

You can do several things to improve execution time:

- Instead of working with Cells, use `arrays` or, even better, `Scripting.Dictionary`. This option alone will speed up quite a lot.
- Sometimes we tend to process data directly on the worksheet, but many basic operations can be done directly in `SQL`, like sums.
- Try avoid redundand operations, like selecting a `Range` and then using the `Selection`. Do your operation directly on the `Range`.

For example you can change this:

```
Range(Cells(t + 1, "A"), Cells(t + a, "AB")).Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
```

To this:

```
Range(Cells(t + 1, "A"), Cells(t + a, "AB")).Delete Shift:=xlUp
```

Following this suggestions should speed things up quite a lot.

Hope this helps.